# Simple select query returning empty result set?

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't explain this. What fundamental thing am I overlooking which is causing this not to work? I have a simple table with only one entry (for testing purposes) at the moment:

```
TABLE votes
vote_id | user_id | image_id | vote_type 
----------------------------------------
43      | 8       | 5        | 1
```

Where `vote_id` is a primary key, `user_id` & `image_id` are foreign keys, and `vote_type` is a boolean

This ridiculously simple select query with 2 `WHERE` clauses won't even return the one entry in the table:

```
SELECT * FROM `votes` WHERE 'user_id' = 8 AND 'image_id' = 5;
```

Even 1 `WHERE` clause doesn't return anything:

```
SELECT * FROM `votes` WHERE 'vote_type' = 1;
```

Yet, a SELECT with no conditions does return the 1 result:

```
SELECT * FROM `votes`;
```

Note, I don't get any errors, I just get told that "MySQL returned an empty result set". What's going on here?

Comment: Could it be your columns aren't of integer type?

Comment: Make sure the fields are string, if they are, use quotation marks in the query. `SELECT * FROM 'votes' WHERE 'user_id' = '8' AND 'image_id' = '5';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need backquotes instead of single quotes.  Try:

```
SELECT * FROM `votes` WHERE `user_id` = 8 AND `image_id` = 5;
```

Single quotes are used for string constants.  So the string "user_id" is not equal to the integer "8".